# How to connect receiver in an Arduino with a motor shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield, robotics

I have an Adafruit motor shield v1 stacked on an Arduino Uno. I want to add a 433Mhz receiver to the Uno so I can control it wirelessly. However as you know the motor shield completely covers the Arduino board and all its pins, except perhaps the analog ones (it appeared to me).

So can you please suggest a way to connect the receiver if possible. I desperately need it and can't afford to buy a Mega now.

Please help asap.

Comment: are there not through-hole "test pads" on the shield PCB that you can solder onto? can you not use the analog pins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adfruit Motor Shield v1 takes digital pins(D12 to D2) left only digital pins (D13,D1,D0) and all Analog pins of Arduino uno. So if you want to hookup RF receiver with Arduino then you have go this way.. connect RF Receiver output to the Digital pin D0 that is RX.

Here the schematic

[image: Wiring RF receiver with Arduino]

Comment: Okay i just google about the sheild and found out pin 2 also remains unused so can i connect the receiver with it? And as u said to connect the receiver with rx,  wont there be problem uploading the sketch to arduino  d another point is does rx pin has any benefit ovr pin 2 for connecting the receiver? Plz confirm regarding the above points

Comment: Yeah You can also connect RF receiver output with pin 2. RF receiver gives DIGITAL output and both pin and Digital pin so there are no difference between Rx pin and Pin 2 for this case . Rx and Tx pin used only for some special cases (like Bluetooth, Serial Terminal e.t.c). while you uploading Sketch on Arduino just disconnect the Rx and Tx pin after uploading sketch connect again otherwise you might have get some error.